# Why does save-svg-as-png produce a blank png?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, png

I'm trying to convert my map, which is an svg, into a png. I've installed save-svg-as-png from https://www.npmjs.com/package/save-svg-as-png, and it seems to be almost working, except that the png that gets downloaded is completely blank.

I'm still very much a beginner so it could be a very basic mistake I'm making. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.24.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Iona\node_modules\save-svg-as-png\lib/saveSvgAsPng.js"></script>

<style> /* set the CSS */

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>

<header>

<h1> Scottish NEAFC Designated Ports </h1>

</header>

<body style="font-family: sans-serif">

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<svg id="myMap" width="400" height="500"></svg>

<p> *UK Border Control Post </p>
<p> List of NEAFC ports available at https://psc.neafc.org/designated-contacts#GBR. </p>

<script>

drawMap()

//Save svg as png
saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("myMap"), "myMap.png", {height: 500});

function drawMap() {

    // The svg to hold the map
    var svg = d3.select("#myMap"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    // Path generator and projection
    var path = d3.geoPath();
    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .center([-4.1826,56.8169])
        .scale(1400)
        .translate([width/2, height/2])
    
    // Bring the data in via a promise

    const files = ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squirrel-star/squirrel-star.github.io/main/scotland.geojson"];
    const quantityByCode = new Map();
    function row(d) {
        quantityByCode.set(d.code, parseFloat(d[option]));
    };
    
    const promises = [];

    files.forEach(function(url, index) {
        promises.push(index ? d3.csv(url, row) : d3.json(url))
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    
    // Any code that depends on 'data' (the information from the promises), in the form data[i] is the ith promise, goes here.
    
    // Add the bubbles' locations

    var markers = [
        {long: -2.0943, lat: 57.1497, port: "Aberdeen"},
        {long: -2.9673, lat: 57.6774, port: "Buckie"},
        {long: -5.6054, lat: 55.4241, port: "Campbeltown"},
        {long: -2.9707, lat: 56.4620, port: "Dundee"},
        {long: -2.0911, lat: 55.8691, port: "Eyemouth"},
        {long: -2.0076, lat: 57.6934, port: "Fraserburgh"},
        {long: -3.7228, lat: 56.0097, port: "Grangemouth"},
        {long: -4.7720, lat: 55.9565, port: "Greenock"},
        {long: -4.1729, lat: 57.6881, port: "Invergordon*"},
        {long: -5.0492, lat: 58.4588, port: "Kinlochbervie"},
        {long: -3.1665, lat: 55.9755, port: "Leith"},
        {long: -1.1493, lat: 60.1530, port: "Lerwick"},
        {long: -5.2426, lat: 58.1462, port: "Lochinver"},
        {long: -5.8272, lat: 57.0038, port: "Mallaig"},
        {long: -3.0164, lat: 56.1848, port: "Methill"},
        {long: -5.4710, lat: 56.4152, port: "Oban"},
        {long: -1.7841, lat: 57.5081, port: "Peterhead"},
        {long: -1.2822, lat: 60.1377, port: "Scalloway"},
        {long: -3.5526, lat: 58.6110, port: "Scrabster"},
        {long: -6.3849, lat: 58.2094, port: "Stornoway"},
        {long: -4.6599, lat: 55.5413, port: "Troon"},
        {long: -5.1613, lat: 57.8954, port: "Ullapool"},
    ];

    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data[0].features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("stroke", "white")
            .attr("stroke-width", ".2")
            // draw each country
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
                )
            // set the color of each country
            .attr("fill", "Gainsboro")

    // Add each bubble.
    svg
        .selectAll("myCircles")
        .data(markers)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0]})
            .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1]})
            .attr("r", 1)
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("stroke", "#41b6c4")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
            .attr("title", function(d) {return d.code})
            
    svg.
        selectAll("text")
            .data(markers)
            .enter()
            .append("text") // append text
                .attr("x", function(d) {return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0]})
                .attr("y", function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]})
                .attr("dx", function(d) { if(d.long > -3.7 && d.port != "Scalloway") {return 1.5} else {return -1.5}; })
                .attr("dy", 1) // set y position of bottom of text
                .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // set anchor y justification
                .text(function(d) {return d.port;}) // define the text to display
                .style("font-size", "4px")
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {if(d.long > -3.7 && d.port != "Scalloway") {return "start"} else {return "end"}; })
                
    });


} // End of function drawMap


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your `drawMap()` function has an asynchronous activity. It will return immediately and the map will only be drawn when all those Promise object are resolved.

Comment: This fixed it - once I moved the savSvgAsPng part inside the promise in drawMap() it worked.

Comment: Good to hear, and Up With King James!